# Client date, time and machine name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

How to retrieve client machine's name, and current time and date to save a log... I need syntax in ASP.NET using c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the client machine name on the server as this information is never sent to the server. You could retrieve the client IP though using the [`Request.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.userhostaddress.aspx) property. The current time on the client could be retrieved using the javascript [`Date`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptdate.php) object. To retrieve the time on the server you could use [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) property.

And by the way, your web server is logging all this information already, so you are probably doing some redundant work.